# Python - how to remove specific words from list?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, replace

I have a list like:

```
 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Web': ['site: www.domain.com'], 'Phone': ['(111) 222-333', '(222) 333-444'], 'VAT': ['987654321'], 'Fax': ['(444) 555-666', '(777) 888-999'], 'E-mail': ['adress: mail@domain.com', 'address: mail2@domain.com'], 'ID': ['number:1234567890']})
```

I want to clean words like: `site:`, `adress:` `number:`.

Output should be:

```
 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Web': ['www.domain.com'], 'Phone': ['(111) 222-333', '(222) 333-444'], 'VAT': ['987654321'], 'Fax': ['(444) 555-666', '(777) 888-999'], 'E-mail': ['mail@domain.com', 'mail2@domain.com'], 'ID': ['1234567890']})
```

I know that I can remove words from specific list item like:

```
for em in d["E-mail"]:
    print(em.replace("address: ","",1))
```

but I'm looking for something that would clean whole list.

Comment: How you assign the values to defaultdict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want the substring  after the `:`, so either splitting will get us the substring or nothing will be removed if there is no `:` in the string:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    d[k] = [s.split(":", 1)[-1].lstrip() for s in v ]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'E-mail': ['mail@domain.com', 'mail2@domain.com'], 'Phone': ['(111) 222-333', '(222) 333-444'], 'ID': ['1234567890'], 'Web': ['www.domain.com'], 'VAT': ['987654321'], 'Fax': ['(444) 555-666', '(777) 888-999']}
```

Using `[-1]` as the index will mean we either get the second of two or the only string if there is nothing split. We also need to `lstrip` any leading whitespace from the substring after splitting.

You could also apply the same logic as you add the data to your defaultdict to  avoid having to iterate over and mutate the dict values after they have already been assigned.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that `.strip()` cleans up any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @PM2Ring, yep, changed to lstrip and added a note.

Comment: Even better. :) FWIW, I'd probably just use `.strip` even though `.lstrip`'s more efficient here - but I guess it depends on how clean the input data is, and if you want to preserve possible trailing spaces in that data.

Answer (score 0):

```
for em in dict:

   if ":" in dict[em]
   a=dict[em].split(":")
   a.remove(a[0])
   print(a)
```

Try this code here

Comment: `a.remove(a[0])` is inefficient. Also, the OP wants the data in a dict (or defaultdict), he doesn't just want to print it.

Comment: did i say [em].split?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Padraic Cunningham response but with regex:

```
In [39]: import re

In [40]: s = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+:\s?')

In [41]: d={'Web': ['site: www.domain.com'], 'Phone': ['(111) 222-333', '(222) 333-444'], 'VAT': ['987654321'], 'Fax': ['(444) 555-666', '(777) 888-999'], 'E-mail': ['adress: mail@domain.com', 'address: mail2@domain.com'], 'ID': ['number:1234567890']}

In [42]: def clean(dict_):
   ....:     for k, v in dict_.items():
   ....:         dict_[k] = map(lambda x: s.sub('', x), v)
   ....:

In [43]: clean(d)
Out[43]:
{'E-mail': ['mail@domain.com', 'mail2@domain.com'],
 'Fax': ['(444) 555-666', '(777) 888-999'],
 'ID': ['1234567890'],
 'Phone': ['(111) 222-333', '(222) 333-444'],
 'VAT': ['987654321'],
 'Web': ['www.domain.com']}
```